# Fully disable tab hover cards in Google Chrome 109

Tags: google-chrome

I want to disable the hover cards in Google Chrome. I have already disabled the the tab preview by changing these settings:

```
chrome://flags/#tab-hover-cards
```

Now the preview is disabled, but not the popup when hovering on a tab. Is there a way to fully disable this popup as well?

[image: popup]

Comment: Here's the active issue tracker for it where they're taking feedback: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215597